# Difference between Websocket and Socket and XMPP?

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, xmpp

Help me out to understand the difference between Socket, Websockets, and XMPP protocols.

Comment: https://erminesoft.com/instant-messaging-protocols-xmpp-vs-websockets-vs-mtproto/

Comment: This question shows no research by your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Socket" is a term usually used to refer to some abstraction in software of what goes on in a plain TCP/IP (or equivalent) conversation. A socket is something provides reliable, point-to-point conversation in data packets between two points identified by IP numbers. Most programming languages or libraries provide something that models a socket in this sense.

Websockets is a protocol that allows socket-like communication to be initiated between a web browser and its cients, as an extension to the basic HTTP protocol. The conversation need not be strictly point-to-point, as it can pass through proxies, as HTTP can. Websocket conversation is initiated by an exchange of headers similar to HTTP.

XMPP is an XML-based messaging protocol, used by "instant" messaging-type applications.